# Django: How to test view context with RequestFactory?

Tags: django, django-tests

I am writing unit tests and creating `request` objects with `RequestFactory` because almost all of my app is behind login and I need to set `request.user` but this way cannot access the `context` of the response to test the values my view sent as part of the response.

When using the Testing client I can get the context this way `response.context_data['form']` and write asserts against it.

What is the proper way of testing views that require login? I also tried inspecting the `response` object with debugger and could not find anything resembling `context`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you don't use the test client. It has support for [logging a user in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login) and then you can assert on the context as you want.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I managed to miss this option. I am also using custom parts of the auth process but hopefully that wont be a issue

Comment: Using RequestFactory is a perfectly valid scenario for views which are really simple. After all it is simpler to just assign a user (without creating a password for example) to the request than to request a login. Perfectly valid IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Test client goes through middleware which might be unnecessary and makes the testing slow.
**Testing should follow F.I.R.S.T**
Fast ,Independent, Repeatable, Self-validating and Thorough.

```
from django.test import RequestFactory, TestCase


class AddNewTopicTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username="sourabh", 
            email="email@something.com", 
            password="Somepassword"
        )
    
    def test_csrf_token_is_present_in_get_request_to_create_topic_view(self):
        url = reverse("new_topic", args=(self.board_obj.slug,))
        request = self.factory.get(url)
        request.user = self.user

        kwargs = {"slug": "some-args"}
        response = CreateTopicView.as_view()(request, **kwargs)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTrue(response.context_data)
```

See also: [Advanced testing topics](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/advanced/)